# If I update an already published book on iTunes Producer, will those changes be pushed to purchasers?

Tags: epub, apple-books

Similar to [this question](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/is-there-a-way-to-publish-an-ebook-distribute-it-and-the-push-updates-to-the-di), but would like to know specifically if there's a way to do this through the iBookstore/iTunes Producer, and what the process might be.

The books are epub2 and epub3, not iBooks Author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this happens automatically.

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12101?locale=en_US

> During the publishing process, you specify whether the book is new or
>   an update to a previously published version. If it is an update, you
>   must provide a new version number. Readers who downloaded your book
>   are notified in iBooks that a new version is available.